# Diffusion model, small example

Tags: sampling

I was wondering if someone would be able to give a small example of how [diffusion models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_model) might be used to sample from a distribution (ie, just given data from a scalar random variable that follows a normal distribution).

Answer (score 0):

When you say sample, do you mean sample from initial condition. You can have a diffusion i.e.:

$$dx(t)=\mu dt +\sigma dw(t) $$

then

$$ x(0) \approx N(0,1) $$

and you can evolve that distribution thru time.

The link you listed is at minimum mistitled. The wiki link is describing the conditioned diffusion. If you know the probability distribution of a diffusion such as the one I listed, you can reverse to the initial distribution. These models are used when you do not necessary know the initial $x(0)$ distribution such as the distribution of all images in the world

Just to give an illustration of the conditioned diffusion (score function whatever), the gradient term will keep switching signs to keep the condition diffusion on the mean through time of the regular diffusion. Here is a picture for illustration and I hope it helps.

[image]

In this next picture assume the surface is the probablity density of the regular diffusion, then this is a path of the conditioned diffusion.

[image]

Also, with the recent application - this is also called reversed diffusion - that just means you are running the time in reverse - you don't have to.